# Unable to connect Public DNS of AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, putty

[image]

Above image consist of login error of putty and ssh connections.

So I dont know the process of getting connected to my EC2 instances

[image]

**Question:** How to connect to our instances using private_key.ppm and putty.

Comment: changed the question string and formatted the question description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
First of all Download private keys from your aws console so that you can use those keys to looged in to user EC2 instances.

like below
```

1. key selection

Fisrt of all decide which public key you wanted to use wheather it is ppm or ppk

- Select platform

Then select platform you gonna use in my case i m using Windows. and connectivity software is putty..

- Copy required data in the sense your Amazon public DNS .

Copy it from your EC2 instance dashboard.

- putty configuration

open up putty ,put `ec2-user@public_address`  Drag your ssh from categories again click on `Auth` and browse your public key you was just downloaded .